# Customize uikit sliders' navigation icons

Tags: html, css, uikit

Instead of uikit default arrow navigation icons(< & >), I need to put my own image or icon. Like bellow image. Is it possible? If so please share.

this is my code

```
<div class="uk-position-relative uk-visible-toggle uk-light" tabindex="-1" uk-slideshow>

<ul class="uk-slideshow-items">
    <li>
        <img src="images/photo.jpg" alt="" uk-cover>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/dark.jpg" alt="" uk-cover>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/light.jpg" alt="" uk-cover>
    </li>
</ul>

<a class="uk-position-center-left uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover" href="#" uk-slidenav-previous uk-slideshow-item="previous"></a>
<a class="uk-position-center-right uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover" href="#" uk-slidenav-next uk-slideshow-item="next"></a>
```

[image: the icons i need]

Answer (score 0):

You can add your icons to the uikit library in the project, and then rebuild(compile) the UI Kit. Have a look into the [documentation](https://getuikit.com/docs/custom-icons) of the uikit Custom icons. After that you should be able to use them like other uikit icons.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can, as the icon isn't part of the set. It's inline SVG. I'm trying to increase the viewBox width via CSS, not sure if that's possible either.